# PHP Download file while converting

Tags: php, mp3

i need a way to download a mp3 file while is converted from m4a to mp3.

I tried this code and it works, but, when i play the song it has wrong duration, if the song has 3 minutes length then when downloaded trough this function has 3:40 or such

```
set_time_limit(0);
$local_file = 'song.mp3';
$download_file = 'song.mp3';
if(file_exists($local_file) && is_file($local_file)) {
header('Content-Description: file transfer');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$download_file);
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg, audio/x-mpeg, audio/x-mpeg-3, audio/mpeg3"); 
$perSecond = 500000; 
$file = fopen($local_file, 'r');
while(!feof($file)) {
    echo fread($file, $perSecond);
    flush();
    sleep(11);
}

}
```

Is there any way to do this? Thank you!

Comment: "converted from m4a to mp3"  Why would you want to do this?  You should never go from a lossy format to another lossy format if you can help it.  You're degrading quality further, adding even more artifacts.  What's worse is that you're doing to a particularly bad codec.  Most everything supports AAC, why would you go to MP3?

Comment: "file while converting"  Where's that conversion process happening?

Comment: What's with the multiple `Content-Type` values?  You only need `audio/mpeg`.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, i have a website that allows you to convert videos/another formats to mp3. The conversion is made using shell_exec on the dedicated server. I found a way to do this doing the conversion on the fly. I want mp3 because people are using it more than other formats, for example, in my car m4a does not work and i have a really good player.

Comment: If you're converting on the fly, and you're missing data, maybe the conversion isn't done yet?

Answer (score 1):

perhaps use [`sendfile`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) to stream the file instead? When using [`fopen`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) for non-text files, specify binary mode with the `b` flag: `fopen($path, 'rb')`.

Comment: thanks for your answer mate.
indeed if i use b flag the duration is good, but on mobile device does not read the mp3 file, also tags like bitrate is missing...
i tried the readfile() but reads only what was converted

Comment: @Marius There is no tag for bitrate.  The bitrate can change per-frame, and is stored in the MPEG frame header.